# Issues while trying to implement multi tenant system using node.js with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have different clients and the idea is to keep their data separate from each other in the same application. We are using node.js with mongodb and mongoose is being used for querying.

This is 'index.js' file in models directory

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var connectionUrl = 'mongodbserverlink/';

var companies = [{ db: 'comp1_db', comp_id: 'com1' }, { db: 'com2_db', comp_id: 'com2' }, { db: 'com3_db', compa_id: 'com3'}];
var connections = {};
var models = {};

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .forEach(function (file) {
        var Schema = file.split('.js')[0];
        if (Schema === 'index') return;
        models[Schema] = require('./' + Schema);
    }); 

companies.forEach(function (company) {
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection(connectionUrl + company.db);
    connections[company.company_id] = {};
    Object.keys(models).forEach(function (Schema) {
        connections[company.company_id][Schema] = conn.model(Schema, models[Schema]);
    });


    conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, company.db + ' connection error in mongodb in the first step!'));


    conn.once('open', function() {
        console.log(company.db + " mongodb connected");
    });
});

module.exports = connections;
```

Here the connection is being made with different databases. The models directory has this index file.

Now in the controller where application logic is being done, this is what we are doing.

```
var models = require('../models');
var comp_id = req.body.comp_id;
db.collectionname.find...(This is not the syntax for find, I just cut it short to keep it simple) // -> this is not working now
```

when we tried logging models object this is what we got

```
models object is: {"com1":{},"com2":{},"com3":{}}
```

and only db when logged gives `{}`

We are facing issues in grasping the complete work... it is because the person who wrote the major chunk is not with us and there is no documentation.

What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is keeping the data separate a requirement from one of the customers, or generally just a good idea given the nature of the data.

Comment: Maybe they are just typos in your example, but there are a lot of inconsistencies in your object keys. For example, `connections[company.company_id] = {};` But the objects in the `companies` array use `comp_id` not `company_id` as a key. The last one, for `com3` is actually `compa_id`. The first `db` value in the `companies` array is `comp1_db`, while the others are `com2_db` and `com3_db`. So, I would start by double-checking your variable / key / value naming. Can you post some examples of the model files that reside in the same directory as `index.js`?

Comment: @JeffKilbride Actually I changed the actual company ids - for obvious reasons. The code in real works fine.

Comment: @TaylorAckley Hi Taylor. We are scaling a product whose base is Data, huge amount of data so that's a needed practice so that it'll be easy to decouple the system based on separate dbs. Second thing is architecture wise it is generally suggested for an enterprise product to have separate dbs for every client.

Comment: That's true, and how we do it for some of our products.   The problem you run into of course is schema changes can get time consuming to migrate.   Especially if you're doing anything custom.

Comment: @TaylorAckley How? The Schema remains same for everyone in our case and one direct change affects all of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have your models exported from the index file. So, in the controller you can do a `var models = require('index');`. From the connections object, you may be able to retrieve the corresponding model: `var companyModel = models[comp_id];`.

Hope it helps.